# How to generate object-object mapping in VS/Resharper

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, resharper

Is there any tools/plugins that can generate "manual" mapping code in VS/Resharper.
I.e. there are 2 classes (Foo & Bar) with the same properties set:

```
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
    public decimal C { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to generate the following code somehow?

```
public Bar Create(Foo foo)
{
    var bar = new Bar();
    bar.A = foo.A;
    bar.B = foo.B;
    bar.C = foo.C;
    return bar;
}
```

Avoid mapping tools like AutoMapper, EmitMapper, etc.

Comment: Could you add this ability to your resharper plugin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can write a T4 template to scan the classes in your project and generate the desired code